# Pine Script volume profile calculation

Tags: pine-script

I don't understand how the Session Volume Profile works. The bull (up) volume should be 930 according to my calculations, but is 568. What am I getting wrong and how should I calculate the price volume? The timeframe used is 1 minute and the Volume Profile should be calculated on the same timeframe (https://www.tradingview.com/support/solutions/43000502040-volume-profile/).

See the video for more information https://photos.app.goo.gl/fnoJy7Mbs6gfPcDw6

Comment: hey @micke were you able to get with what you were looking for? Coincidentally, I am in the same boat now trying to understand the volume profile

Comment: Hi! Unfortunately not :/